# Make two tables the same size?

Tags: tables

How do I make two tables with different the same size?

[image: Picture showing the problem]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{Summary of glioblastoma qualitative radiogenomic results}}                                                                                                                                           \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Reference}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Year}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Gene}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Method}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Qualitative features associated with gene mutations}} \\ \hline
\cite{carillo_table}                                        & 2012                               & IDH1                               & Logistic Regression                  & Frontal lobe, les enhancement, smaller size                                       \\
\cite{paldor_table}                                        & 2016                               & IDH1                               & Chi-square test                      & Frontal Lobe                                                                      \\
\cite{aghi_table}                                        & 2005                               & EGFR                               & Student t-test                       & Increased edema-enhancing tumor ratio; ill-defined T2 margins                     \\ \cite{ellingson_table}
                                         & 2013                              & EGFR                               & Fisher's exact test                  & Left temporal lobe                                                                \\  \cite{young_table} 
                                         & 2013                             & EGFR                               & Wilcoxon signed-rank test            & Lower ADC                                                                         \\ \cite{gupta_table}
                                         & 2015                               & EGFR                               & Wilcoxon signed-rank test            & Increased cerebral blood volume, decreased peak signal recovery                                                       
\end{tabular}
}%
\caption{Radiogenomics studies carried out on glioblastoma that have studied the association between \textit{qualitative} imaging features and gene mutations in IDH and EGFR; source: Chow et. al (2017)\cite{imaging_hetero}}
\label{table:qualitative}
\end{table}
```

and

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Summary of glioblastoma quantitative radiogenomic results}                                                                                            \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Refrence} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Year} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Gene} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Radiomics features} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Classifier} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Accuracy} \\ \hline
\cite{zhang_table}                              & 2017                      & IDH1                      & FOS, SOS                                & Random Forest                   & 0.89                          \\
\cite{levner_table}                              & 2009                      & MGMT                      & SOS                                     & Neural Network                  & 0.877                         \\
\cite{korfiatis_table}                              & 2016                      & MGMT                      & SOS                                     & SVM, Random Forest              &                               \\
\cite{kickingereder_table}                              & 2016                      & EGFR                      &      FOS                                   &                                 & 0.63                          \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}           & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}      & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}            & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}         
\end{tabular}
\caption{Radiogenomics studies carried out on glioblastoma that have studied the association between \textit{quantitative} imaging features and gene mutations; source: Chow et. al (2017)\cite{imaging_hetero} }
\label{table:quantitative}
\end{table}
```

I tried solving it with `\adjustbox` but this didn't help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Don't resize a `tabular` using stuff like `\resizebox`, it leads to inconsistent font sizes. Instead you could refactor your `tabular`s to not extend the margins, or use `\small` to slightly reduce the font size in a *good* manner.

Comment: Refactoring could be done with the help of `tabularx`: use `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccclX}` instead of your `\begin{tabular}` for the first table. And you shouldn't use `c` columns for everything. Stuff containing labels or years might look good this way, but columns containing text (even if only few words like your `Method` or `Classifier` column) should be set using `l` or if it contains much text `p` or `X` (the latter if `tabularx` is used).

Comment: And don't use vertical rules, ever.

Comment: Two tables with different *what*?

Answer (score 7):

I would build your tables more like the ones below. I removed the first head row as it seems redundant to the `\caption`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{x}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\small
\noindent
\tabcolsep=.7\tabcolsep
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccc>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}x{.7}x{1.3}}
  \toprule
  Reference & Year & Gene & Method
    & Qualitative features associated with gene mutations \\
  \midrule
  \cite{carillo_table}   & 2012 & IDH1 & Logistic Regression
    & Frontal lobe, les enhancement, smaller size \\
  \cite{paldor_table}    & 2016 & IDH1 & Chi-square test
    & Frontal Lobe \\
  \cite{aghi_table}      & 2005 & EGFR & Student t-test 
    & Increased edema-enhancing tumor ratio; ill-defined T2 margins \\
  \cite{ellingson_table} & 2013 & EGFR & Fisher's exact test
    & Left temporal lobe \\  
  \cite{young_table}     & 2013 & EGFR & Wilcoxon signed-rank test
    & Lower ADC \\
  \cite{gupta_table}     & 2015 & EGFR & Wilcoxon signed-rank test
    & Increased cerebral blood volume, decreased peak signal recovery \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabular}{cccclS[table-format=1.3]}
  \toprule
  Reference & Year & Gene & Radiomics features & Classifier & {Accuracy} \\
  \midrule
  \cite{zhang_table}         & 2017 & IDH1 & FOS, SOS & Random Forest
    & 0.89 \\
  \cite{levner_table}        & 2009 & MGMT & SOS      & Neural Network
    & 0.877 \\
  \cite{korfiatis_table}     & 2016 & MGMT & SOS      & SVM, Random Forest
    & \\
  \cite{kickingereder_table} & 2016 & EGFR & FOS      &
    & 0.63 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the second `tabular` is slightly smaller. I also left out the `table` environment, but that shouldn't change much. `\tabcolsep=.7\tabcolsep` reduces the separation between the columns to 70 %. The `\noindent` is not necessary inside of `table`. If the two `tabular`s end up in different `table` environments, you should use `\small` and `\tabcolsep=.7\tabcolsep` in both of them.

**EDIT:** One should mention, that the sum of all arguments to the `x` columns in one `tabularx` must total the number of `x` columns in that `tabularx`. So if you use 2 `x` columns, the sum must be 2.

Answer (score 6):

slightly modified nice [Skillmon's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon) answer:

[image]

main differences are:

- both table use `tabularx` environment
- the first three columns use the same definition for columns type
- `tablecolsep` is determined on more "latex"/usual way by `\setlength`
- `X` column determined by `tabularx` is redefined more concise and common for all use in tables
- differences are in code indicated by `%<---`

mwe:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % <--- new

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\linewidth\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} % <--- changed

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % <--- changed
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc>{\centering}p{4em}L{.7}L{1.3}}  % <--- changed
  \toprule
  Reference & Year & Gene & Method
    & Qualitative features associated with gene mutations \\
  \midrule
  \cite{carillo_table}   & 2012 & IDH1 & Logistic Regression
    & Frontal lobe, les enhancement, smaller size \\
  \cite{paldor_table}    & 2016 & IDH1 & Chi-square test
    & Frontal Lobe \\
  \cite{aghi_table}      & 2005 & EGFR & Student t-test
    & Increased edema-enhancing tumor ratio; ill-defined T2 margins \\
  \cite{ellingson_table} & 2013 & EGFR & Fisher's exact test
    & Left temporal lobe \\
  \cite{young_table}     & 2013 & EGFR & Wilcoxon signed-rank test
    & Lower ADC \\
  \cite{gupta_table}     & 2015 & EGFR & Wilcoxon signed-rank test
    & Increased cerebral blood volume, decreased peak signal recovery \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc>{\centering}p{4em}c L{1} S[table-format=1.3]}  % <--- changed
  \toprule
  Reference & Year & Gene & Radiomics features & Classifier & {Accuracy} \\
  \midrule
  \cite{zhang_table}         & 2017 & IDH1 & FOS, SOS & Random Forest
    & 0.89 \\
  \cite{levner_table}        & 2009 & MGMT & SOS      & Neural Network
    & 0.877 \\
  \cite{korfiatis_table}     & 2016 & MGMT & SOS      & SVM, Random Forest
    & \\
  \cite{kickingereder_table} & 2016 & EGFR & FOS      &
    & 0.63 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. It would be helpful, I think, if you provided a sentence or two to note how your answer differs from @Skillmon's.

Comment: @Mico, it is indicated in code by `% <---`. this is for me simpler than my tourture of english language :-). i will give my best to add some comments asap.

Comment: @Mico, done ...

Comment: Nice modifications (though I liked my `x` as a more general column specifier than your `L`). Note that you should set `\linewidth` in `L`, so a better definition would be the one I provided plus `\raggedright\arraybackslash` (see section 4.3 of the `tabularx` documentation).